# Continuous probability calculation of rectangular region

Tags: probability, probability-density, probability-theory

Ok I am asking this question because there are tags with probability so dont send me to mathoverflow which only accepts PHD level questions. Here is my question:

Consider a sample space that is the rectangular region [0,1]×[0,2], i.e., the set of all pairs (x,y) that satisfy 0≤x≤1 and 0≤y≤2. Consider a “uniform" probability law, under which the probability of an event is half of the area of the event. Find the probability of the following events:

ok the area is LxB for rectangle which is 2 here? We get it by plotting the coords and getting a triangle which we multiply by 2 to get area of rectangle

a) The two components x and y have the same values.
   This is 0 because  p(event) = 1/2*A= 1 so they cannot be same

b) The value, x, of the first component is larger than or equal to the value, y, of the second component.

Do I integrate xy=2 so y=2/x between x=1 and y=2? Then find the probability P(event) =1/2 of this integration result?

c) The value of x^2 is larger than or equal to the value of y.

I integrate the same but the equation y=(2/x)^2 ?

Thanks
Rahman

Comment: This question is suitable for math.stackexchange.com (which is a separate forum from mathoverflow). That said, keep in mind that the way the probability law is defined, it is just the ordinary Lebesgue measure normalized so that the mass over the whole space is 1 (and the constant of proportionality is just 1/2). Therefore all your questions can be answered by computing the area (Lebesgue measure on R^2) and then multiplying by 1/2. What is the area of any point or line in R^2? Therefore what is the P(x = y) ? Likewise what is the area of x >= y? or x^2 >= y?

Comment: Thanks you for the clarification @RobertDodier